# Features - NHibernate versus Writing Custom Object-Relational Mapper

Tags: .net, nhibernate, orm

I'm looking for a list of all the features you would have implement in a custom object relational mapper (ORM) to meet all the features of NHibernate.

to start:

1. database portability through different drivers and dialects
2. caching
3. lazy loading
4. custom SQL
5. query interface - LINQ, Criteria, QBE (Query By Example)
6. basic and advanced mapping functionality (ex. discriminator columns, *examples*)
7. support for transactions and unit of work
8. [Multi-Criteria](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2007/05/20/NHibernate-Multi-Criteria.aspx)
9. [Multi-Query](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2006/12/05/NHibernateMutliQuerySupport.aspx)
10. Batching
11. Hooks to supplement/override functionality

<Insert yours Here>

See another list here: [25 Reasons Not To Write Your Own Object Relational Mapper](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2006/05/12/25ReasonsNotToWriteYourOwnObjectRelationalMapper.aspx) from Ayende Rahien

Answer (score 3):

Ayende published a near complete list of important ORM features here:
http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2006/05/12/25ReasonsNotToWriteYourOwnObjectRelationalMapper.aspx

An important one that is missing from your list is IsDirty/State Change checking. Identity Map is another important one which enables a lot of the other features such as IsDirty.

Comment: So would you say that Identity Map is the feature and IsDirty an aspect of that feature? or would you list it as 2 separate items?

Comment: Hard to say. Identity Map is a feature itself but it is often used as the heart of other features such as dirty tracking, caching, and unit of work. Those features can be implemented w/o identity map and Identity map can be implemented without those features. However, they tend to go hand-in-hand.

Answer (score 2):

Multi query,

Batching.

And most importantly: Hooks to supplement/override whatevery functionality that works in ways you did not expect/want/feel like that day.

The last part is one place where NHibernate excels.

Answer (score 1):

Some kind of query interface (like linq or Criteria)

Some kind of mapping functionallity

Support for transactions and Unit of work